# how to swap between spl tokens inside rust anchor program

Tags: anchor, solana-program, cpi, staking, swap

I'm going to implement spl token swap with rust inside Anchor project.
Basically it's about compounding logic in staking project, so I have to swap reward tokens into stake token and add it to staking pool.
Apparently I have reward token amount, and stake and reward token mint.
So if I assume this token pair has liquidity in dex, like Raydium, how can I swap reward to stake tokens?

here's the similiar approach in solidity, I'd like to know how I can convert this to rust-anchor.

Thanks in advance.

```
function compoundReward(IAggregator.Trade memory _trade) external payable nonReentrant {
        UserInfo storage user = userInfo[msg.sender];

        if (user.amount == 0) return;

        uint256 pending = (user.amount * accTokenPerShare) / PRECISION_FACTOR - user.rewardDebt;
        if (pending > 0) {
            require(availableRewardTokens() >= pending, "Insufficient reward tokens");
            if (totalEarned > pending) {
                totalEarned = totalEarned - pending;
            } else {
                totalEarned = 0;
            }
            paidRewards = paidRewards + pending;
            emit Compound(msg.sender, pending);
///// Especially this part    
            if (address(stakingToken) != address(rewardToken)) {
                pending = _safeSwap(pending, address(rewardToken), address(stakingToken), address(this), _trade);
            }
/////
            if (hasUserLimit) {
                require(pending + user.amount <= poolLimitPerUser, "User amount above limit");
            }

            totalStaked = totalStaked + pending;
            user.amount = user.amount + pending;

            emit Deposit(msg.sender, pending);
        }

        user.rewardDebt = (user.amount * accTokenPerShare) / PRECISION_FACTOR;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a possible solution myself at [here](https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-contract-instructions/blob/master/tests/amm-proxy/programs/amm-proxy/src/instructions/swap_base_in.rs), although
I'll have to figure out all the params from the data I have.